# I'm missing something in how you view an object from localStorage call

Tags: angular

I have the following call to localstorage that I know returns an object of a JWT.

```
console.log('You have stored the following: ' + window.localStorage.getItem(this.LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY));
```

But in the consol.log I'm just getting object Object.

I've tried to pars it with .json(), but that doesn't work.

Comment: change `window.localStorage.getItem(this.LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY)` to `localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY')`

Comment: Your problem is at saving, not at getting. Show how it has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the key into the getItem method. The getItem() method when given a key will return the keys value.

Try: `window.localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY')`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem